# ClojureScript: require "goog.dom query" as q

Tags: clojurescript

I'm a bit confused with the import and require semantics..

I'm trying to use the query function inside the dom section of Google's clojure library.

```
(import '(goog.dom query))
(def q query)
```

Unfortunately it's not working with require :as :

```
(require '(goog.dom [query :as q]))
```

By this chance, I found out that the query function is deprecated. I don't quite get why. I'm just looking for a simple un-fancy abstraction (rather convenient simplification) to make dom manipulations/selections. I know there are tons, I just need a shortcut for not writing helpers like by-id select for every small project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path. You should use require in this case. Import is for a class that you want to construct.

```
(ns foo
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom])
  (:import [goog History]))

(dom/getElement "app")
(History.)
```

If you are using a figwheel repl, you can do this instead

```
(require 'goog.dom)
(goog.dom/getElement "app")
```

or

```
(require '[goog.dom :refer [getElement]])
(getElement "app")
```

or similar.

`query` is no longer avaliable, but there are plenty of useful functions like getElement getElementByClass getElementsByTagNameAndClass etc

For repl interaction you might be better using querySelector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector instead:

```
(js/document.querySelector ".myclass")
```